# Ubuntu 16.04 - latest Kernel (4.15.0-132 generic) upgrade cause Internet Network to fail

Tags: networking, kernel

> **Previous Kernel version**: 4.15.0-128-generic
>
> **After update Kernel version**: 4.15.0-132 generic

My Ubuntu Machine is set up with network Lan Port.

- **network 1:** Link to internet - dhcp)
- **IP**: 192.168.1.11

**Network 2:**

- Link to Internal Network - direct to a printer
- IP: 192.168.11.11
  Routes > Use this connection only internally for its network - enabled.

After the update, my internet network will not work. 
However, when I disconnect my Internal network, the internet network will be able to connect to the internet. Anyone has an idea on this issue?

Comment: Not going to be of help with this question but a heads up for you 16.04 is EOL in April of this year time to think upgrade.

Comment: Hi nobody. When i have no output when i type dkms status.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know kernel 4.15.0-132 is not working properly as many people are reporting weird issues. On my machine, after that upgrade the USB keyboard and mouse stop working. I tried with a PS2 keyboard and mouse and it works fine. I haven't found a solution for that yet so my suggestion is to roll back to 4.15.0-128 and wait for a next release. That worked fine for me.

Comment: thanks! I manage to found the solution after visiting various network thread.
It seems my local network has a dns setting of 8.8.8.8 that cause this issue. By removing it seems my internet network is working again.

This only occur after the update of 4.15.0-132.